# Hibernate - Save Entity within PostDeleteEventListener in the same Transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to perform a soft delete (i.e. move a record to another archived table) every time an entity record is deleted. Triggers are not the option.
I'm trying to leverage Hibernate **PostDeleteEventListener** for that.
The issue is that it's not possible to use `event.getSession().save(anotherEntity)` within listener itself as it's simply ignored (simply not propagated to db).
I tried to add an explicit `event.getSession().flush()` after save  - but this doesn't work either as flush() method call retriggers the same Hibernate listeners from the scratch and they collide.

I understand that I can make this in a separate transaction, but I need in the same.

Is there any option for this at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database that you use, it would probably be easiest to replace the SQL statement that is used for the delete by a SQL merge statement. See [this post](https://thorben-janssen.com/implement-soft-delete-hibernate/#:%7E:text=To%20implement%20a%20soft%20delete%2C%20you%20need%20to%20override%20Hibernate%27s,when%20you%20delete%20the%20entity.) as an example.

Comment: This is not the variant I'm targeting. I need to move record to a separate archive table.

Comment: Oh, right. Merge wouldn't delete the original row. So which DB are you on? On PostgreSQL you could model this with writable CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

As Spring Data REST is used - solved the issue using its events support - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events